# How to know whether addition has been done in a parallel binary adder?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, binary

I am little new to electronics and getting some high level overview of digital electronics. The question is that how to know whether addition has been performed in a logic circuit.
For example I have a adder and want to add two numbers (say all zero) how can I know whether the calculation has been done. Say I want to save the result in some small flip flop only when the calculations are performed but since the default state of all logic gate is zero and our result is also zero so how can I differentiate between default zero and result of zero.

Comment: You are supposed to know what the worst case propagation delay is for the longest-time combinatorial path. Then you make sure that your clocking is at least that long. There are some computers that are not clocked, but are asynchronous. But I don't know much about them.

Comment: Related question about synchronous logic (and how it relates to propagation delay): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93875/35022

Comment: https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/bitstream/handle/1828/6986/Alghamdi_Abdulmajeed_MEng_2015.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was looking for these stuffs!

Comment: Static timing analysis will tell you. Now learn the static timing analysis tool for the toolchain you are using.